# package won't install correctly using apt-get

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, ftp

Hey there, I'm currently having problems installing proftpd correctly.

At some point the pakage was already installed but when I try to install don't get a selection screen to preconfigure the server neither are any config files created.

I already tried to purge/reinstall/install/remove/clean/autoclean via apt-get but nothing seems to fix the problem.

Is there a way to force a "clean/fresh" install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright I fixed it. The config files where bound to another package (proftpd-basic).

So using the following commands fixed the problems:

```
apt-get purge proftp*
apt-get install proftpd
```

Comment: Note that you can use `apt-get purge` in place of `apt-get remove --purge`. That's unless you are using a very old version of APT (older than mid-2007).

Comment: @Tshepang urghs I probably should look at the date of the posts I read more often - thanks :)

Comment: How is it that the simple solutions always go un-noticed? I was just beating my head against the desk trying to remove samba. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

*Purge* and *install* should work, so you may have some more severe underlying problem.

You may also try:

`dpkg-reconfigure proftpd`

and see what results you get.

Answer (score 1):

To reinstall:

```
apt-get install --reinstall proftpd
```

If this does not work, uninstall, remove all its configuration, and install again:

```
apt-get remove --purge proftpd
rm -rf /etc/proftpd
apt-get install proftpd
```